# Почему в "Docker logs" не попадают логи от Monolog?

Tags: php, docker, логирование

Всем привет. Налаживаю работу с логами, я хочу зацепить некий агрегатор и собирать все логи им. В агрегатор попадают логи, которые видны в docker logs (тоесть из потоков stdout и stderr).

В моем приложении, я пытаюсь направить некую запись в stdout поток и увидеть ее с помощью команды docker logs:

```
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('MyTestName');
$handler = new StreamHandler('php://stdout', Logger::DEBUG);
$logger->pushHandler($handler);
$logger->error('My test error message');
```

Однако в выхлопе docker logs светится только nginx, более никакие логи не попадают.

[image: docker_logs]

Подскажите, что я упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Кратко:

У каждого приложения в Linux свой `stdin`, `stdout` и `stderr`, в логи докера попадает вывод самого Nginx, а не процесса, который он запускает (у него выводы свои).

Подробнее:

Вот так это работает: в докере работает Nginx, и именно его выводы stdin и stdout попадают в логи. Если взять образ официальный образ `nginx`, то там есть:

```
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
```

который указывает через симлинк на `/dev/stdout`:

```
ls -ld /var/log/nginx/access.log
# вывод:
... /var/log/nginx/access.log -> /dev/stdout
```

А докер цепляет этот `/dev/stdout`

PHP же выводит сообщения в `stdout`, который попадает на `stdin` веб-сервера Nginx, и он с ним ничего не делает (тут смотря какой SAPI, на `fpm-fcgi` и `cgi-fcgi` именно так, а на `fcgiwrap` вывод все же попадет).

Решения (подходят только если PHP и Nginx в одном контейнере):

- писать напрямую в `/dev/stdout`
- настроить Nginx, чтобы он "транслировал", я кажется видел какую-то такую настройку, но не уверен

В каком-то образе видел симлинк `/var/log/syslog` -> `/dev/stdout`, поэтому, еще один вариант:

- писать в сислог
- сделать симлинк сислога на `/dev/stdout`

И еще один вариант - сделать симлинк из своего скрипта перед `new StreamHandler`:

```
# это код на PHP
`ln -sf /proc/self/fd /dev/`
```

Буду рад, если вы проверите все варианты.

Comment: Получается у меня 2 разных контейнера. В одном nginx, а в другом php. И вот, что странно, в конейнере с php идут логи nginx, а в контейнере с nginx, логи пустые. Возможно я не правильно приготовил это все.

Comment: @Nepster, добавьте в вопрос все Dockerfile и команды, как запускаете и как смотрите